# Averaging Values of Documents Column and Displaying in Document Set Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I tried creating a calculated column but it just applies it to each individual item instead of averaging the values from each item together. So for example, I have a document set and within that document set, I have let's say 4-5 document items. Each of those list/library items has a value from 1-10 in a column called rank.

How could I get all of those Rank values, then average them and display them in say a column on the containing document set?

Is this possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a "calculated column" way of doing it, but you could probably do it with some client-side code.  Not sure where exactly you would put it... maybe as part of the document set home page?  But in theory you could use Javascript to

- Figure out what document set you were in
- Use the REST API to get the files inside the document set
- Then get the *list items* for those files
- Then get the rank column values from those items
- Average them and pop the result onto the page somewhere

Maybe you could do it as a [field customizer extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer) for a text or number field that you add to the document set?

Comment: That is what I figured at first, the issue is you have to pull the files individually through rest along side the document set, there is no way to pull the document set and have the files as its children in the object response. That would make it so much easier where as I will have to check for file type with this

Comment: That's not entirely true, I don't think... I just did a test where I stated with the item ID of a document set, and got the folder name and the file names of the files all in one call by doing: `GET` `.../items(3)?$select=Title,ID,Folder/Name,Folder/Files/Name&$expand=Folder,Folder/Files`.

Comment: And actually, it looks like you don't even have to get the files first, and then make a second call to get the files' list item to get the rank column values, because you can do `GET` `...items(3)?$select=Title,ID,Folder/Name,Folder/Files&$expand=Folder,Folder/Files,Folder/Files/ListItemAllFields` which gives you all the columns of the list item(s) of the file(s)!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but what if I want to get all the list items, not by ID because there will be an unknown amount that will always change

Comment: I thought you wanted to do this per document set? In my example there the ID in `items(3)` is the ID of the document set itself, the rest of the query will get the columns of all the files within the document set, no matter how many there are. If you want to get the data for _all_ of the document sets in the library at the same time I suppose you could just omit the ID part and do `GET` `...items?$select=Title,ID,Folder/Name,Folder/Files&$expand=Folder,Folder/Files,Folder/Files/ListItemAllField`

Comment: Since the document sets are filtered/grouped by Team then position, can I filter multiple ajax calls to get different results based on the Team? `GET ...items?$select=Title,ID,Folder/Name,Folder/Files&$expand=Folder,Folder/Files,Folder/Files/ListItemAllField$?Team eq ‘Team1`

Comment: So I got the logic for the GET request right, but the response I get is a 404 telling me that it doesn't exist at the request parameter? I have the url correct, the list url is `baseurl.sharepoint.com/SiteName/PlayerLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx` and for my GET I use `https://baseurl.sharepoint.com/SiteName/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('PlayerLibrary')/items?$select=Title,ID,Folder/Name,Folder/Files&$expand=Folder,Folder/Files,Folder/Files/ListItemAllField"`

Comment: Yes, you use the `$filter` Odata query. `GET ...items?$select=Title,ID,Folder/Name,Folder/Files&$expand=Folder,Folder/Files,Folder/Files/ListItemAllFields&$filter=Team eq 'Team1'`  See [how to use oData query operations in SP REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests).

Comment: `ListItemAllFields` plural, with an 's' at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132225/discussion-between-beerusdev-and-dylan-cristy).

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, it is impossible to realize your design by creating calculated columns.

I suggest you can create **Microsoft Flow** to realize your design.

**The general process is as follows:**

1. Count how many documents there are in the Document Set
2. Count the total Rank of all documents: SUM (Rank)
3. Calculate the [Total Rank] / [Number of documents]
4. Update this value to the Document Set

We suggest that you can go to the [Microsoft Power Automate Community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Power-Automate/ct-p/MPACommunity) to get more professional help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have been doing some research on how to get a flow like this to work. I have created a recurring flow so that way it checks and updates on a daily/weekly basis. The one part that I am confused about is how to check through all the different document sets to get the document count. Usually, when I use a Rest API to get items in a document library it counts the document sets separately from the items it contains.

Lastly, I am not sure if this matters, but the document library is grouped by Team, then it is grouped by Position.

Comment: Under position, there are the document sets that have the player rankings attached to the player file.